# Why AsEnumerable also execute filter on server

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I'm using Linq to Entities in my program, and i have the following two simple queries:

```
var result = dbContext.Customers.Where(c => c.Name == "Mostafa").ToList();
var result2 = dbContext.Customers.Where(c => c.Name == "Mostafa").AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

when i run the SQL Profiler, i found that the generated SQL Query is the same for both of the queries !
the questions is why in the second query, although i'm using asEnumerable, executes the filtering on the server side ?

Update:
The filtering was applied on memory instead of the server when changing the second query to be like this:

```
var result2 = dbContext.Customers.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.Name == "Mostafa").ToList();
```

Thanks to @Willem Van Onsem

Comment: Shouldn't you then use `AsEnumerable()` before the `Where(..)`?

Comment: Please explain why you think the two statements should generate different SQL statements.

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem, your solution works.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, i was expecting that when using asEnumerable, the generated SQL query won't include the filtering as the filtering will be applied in the memory not on the server.

Comment: That would only happen if you placed `.AsEnumerable()` *before* `.Where(...)`.

Comment: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AsEnumerable()` makes the *remainder* of the query execute locally. Anything earlier than the `AsEnumerable()` is still part of the `IQueryable` execution flow. For example, think about this (imagining an `Age` property):

```
var result = dbContext.Customers
    .Where(c => c.Name == "Mostafa")
    .Where(c => c.Age == 18)
    .ToList();
```

That would result in SQL which filtered by name and age. Compare that with this:

```
var result = dbContext.Customers
    .Where(c => c.Name == "Mostafa")
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(c => c.Age == 18)
    .ToList();
```

That would filter by name in the SQL, but it would filter by age locally (in memory).

Comment: You could also state that doing `.AsEnumerable().ToList()` (without anything in between) is kind of pointless